# firebase realtime db with FCM for implementing a chat

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-cloud-messaging

I'm developing an **Android chat application** **and it seems I need to send each message both via FCM and also save to realtime DB.**

I use Firebase realtime DB for storing and sending messages. I still need to send each message (or at least the message id) also via the FCM. I'm afraid that if I DON'T do it, and send FCM only when the app is in background, the users might miss some incoming messages.

Assume the design is like WhatsApp. Each conversation opens a separate activity, presenting the messages in that conversation.

E.g. I'm in a chat with person A, at this time person B sends me a message. I need to have an active listener in all the conversations I have, to get to know I have a new message from B.
 This means I will need to put listeners to a Service, and not to Activity (because activity is representing one active conversation with its messages).

Putting listeners on service seems not reliable enough (what if android kills the service? Until I restart it, I might miss some of new messages and will see them only when I enter the relevant conversation, so that I get them from database).

**For the above reason, it seems I have to send the FCM notification for each message that is sent, in addition to storing it to the database.
Does it sound reasonable? Is there a better way of achieving reliable messaging?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is indeed quite common to send cloud messages to a device even when the user has the app open and in the foreground. You'd in that case simply ignore the message in the `onMessageReveived` of your app.

Comment: Thanks. It seems that if anyway I need to send all the messages via FCM, there is no advantage in using the Realtime DB for the messaging (except messages backup on cloud). Am I right?

Comment: The database will have a persistent log of all your messages. Whether that is necessary for your app, only you cal tell.

Comment: Can I be sure that FCM won't limit my app in the amount of messages I can send via it in millisecond? When the app has large traffic, my app server will have to send a large amount of FCMs each millisecond....

Comment: @user2924714 did you find any solution.. would be really helpful if you could share some of your experience..